# Login API method returning 400 Bad request in Xamarin Forms

Tags: api, asp.net-core, authentication, xamarin.forms

I have a login API method in Xamarin for which I am using a .net core project.The back end login in the web application works perfectly returning the token once I am logged in,but on the client side in Xamarin I am having troubles with it as the response returns a 400 Bad request.I checked the API and everything seems to be fine.I pass the token in the headers for the request along with the credentials and I am checking for the request.
This is the **client side** API:

```html
  public async Task<string> Login(string email, string password)
        {
            var urlLogin = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/Token/";
            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", email),
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
            });

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var authData = string.Format("{0}:{1}", email, password);
            var authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authData));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authHeaderValue);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formContent);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            try
            {
                CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                var responseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(urlLogin, content).Result;
                if(responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login succesful!", "Welcome", "ok", "cancel");
                    await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new UsersPage());
                }
                else
                {
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Wrong credentials", "Please try again!", "ok", "cancel");
                }
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
                throw;
            }




            return "";
        }
```

The **server-side** login api:

```html
   
   [HttpPost]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Post(User userData)
        {
            if (userData != null && userData.Email != null && userData.Password != null)
            {
                var user = await GetUser(userData.Email, userData.Password);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    //create claims details based on the user information
                    var claims = new[] {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, config["Jwt:Subject"]),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim("Id", user.Id.ToString()),
                    new Claim("Name", user.Name),
                    new Claim("Phone", user.Phone.ToString()),
                    new Claim("Email", user.Email),
                    new Claim ("ConfPassword",user.ConfPassword)
                   };

                    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["Jwt:Key"]));

                    var signIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(config["Jwt:Issuer"], config["Jwt:Audience"], claims, expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), signingCredentials: signIn);

                    return Ok(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Invalid credentials");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        private async Task<User> GetUser(string email, string password)
        {
            return await _context.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == email && u.Password == password);
        }
```

**User.cs**

```html
   public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
       
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
     
        public string Phone { get; set; }
     
        public string Password { get; set; }
      
        public string ConfPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with the API?I am new in working with mobile API so please bear with me.

Comment: how is the `User` class defined?  It doesn't appear that what you're sending from the client and what the server expects for that data are the same.

Comment: @Jason I edited the question and added the User class.I'm sorry but I don't understand...isn't the email and password enough for the login method?

Comment: your client is passing fields named "username" and "password" which have no mapping on the server User object.  If your server expects a `User` object a better approach would be to create a `User` object on the client and serialize it.

Comment: I already have a User class on the client side which is the same as the one on the server.So what you're saying if I understand correctly is that I should use the User class from the client,serialize it and pass it to the StringConent method.The thing is that I only need the password and the email.If I do that won't I serialize the entire class?

Comment: if you only want to pass email and password then update your API method to only require those two fields instead of the entire User object

Comment: @Jason thank you so much for your help.I think I got it! I will get back with a possible solution.Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make it work as @Jason suggested.This is the working method on the **client side**:

```html
  public async Task<string> Login(User user)
        {
            var urlLogin = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/Token/";
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var authData = string.Format("{0}:{1}", user.Email, user.Password);
            var authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authData));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authHeaderValue);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            try
            {
                CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                var responseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(urlLogin, content).Result;
                if(responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login succesful!", "Welcome", "ok", "cancel");
                    await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new UsersPage());
                }
                else
                {
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Wrong credentials", "Please try again!", "ok", "cancel");
                }
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
                throw;
            }




            return "";
        }
```